# Troubleshooting friendly_id w/ Rails 4: working as expected in rails console, getting RecordNotFound error from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I've been successfully using friendly_id with multiple models in my Rails 4 app. I previously had two models that I've decided to combine (Terminals and Locations). The Terminals show action was previously working with friendly_id, where I could visit /terminals/albany and get the Terminal with the slug 'albany'.

I've gone through the bulk of the refactor to condense down to just Locations, and am on the last piece (fixing views). Along the way I've been testing things in Rails Console and using rspec, and things seem to work as expected. There are other models that still work as expected as well.

Now that I'm working on the new show page for Locations, I'm getting the following error when attempting to visit /locations/albany:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in LocationsController#show
Couldn't find Location with id=albany
```

However, when I visit /locations/5, it successfully loads the record. It also works in Rails Console:

```
Location.find(5)                 # returns the correct location object
Location.find(5).slug            # returns 'albany'
Location.friendly.find('albany') # returns the correct location object
```

When I look at the generated slugs in Rails dbconsole, they all look like they were generated correctly and there are no duplicates.

Here's my model:

```
Class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: [:slugged, :history]

  def slug_candidates
    [
      :name,
      [:name, :zip],
      [:name, :zip, :location_type],
    ]
  end
end
```

And here's my show action in my controller:

```
def show
  @locations = Location.friendly.find(params[:id])
end
```

I'm stumped! Any hints?

Comment: Just pinging - anybody out there?

Comment: I'm also stuck on this -- were you able to figure anything out?

Comment: Either of you figure this out? Getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding :finders?

```
friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: [:slugged, :history, :finders]
```

Comment: This fixed the issue described above for me!

Comment: I have the same issue and it seems to work with `:finders` enabled, but I think that shouldn't even be necessary.

Comment: The latest version of friendly id requires that you prefix any .find method with .friendly... so Model.friendly.find() rather than just Model.find(). The finders method will make it work without

Comment: But if you look at the example in the opening post, it does use friendly.find - that is the whole point of the question i think.
I have same problem. Anyone?