# Rails 4/ ajax - NoMethodError - undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass - Passing variable to js modal

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a pretty simple Ruby On Rails app with bootstrap 3 for the front end: I have Deals, and each Deal has_many Opportunities.

On each Deal page (url of deal page is for example myapp.com/id=1), I want to have a textual link that says "view deal's opportunities" and when clicked, it trigger when clicked the appearance of content inside a Bootstrap modal.

I'm getting all mixed up because on this Deal Page, I use Deal's controller action called "showcase". BUT to generate the modal via ajax,as you see below, I use another action called "show_opportunities" and inside it, the app seems not to know @deal (because@deal is defined in a different Deal's action). **I think that where the problem comes form but I am not totally sure.**

Here is the error I am getting and my code:

```
Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Couldn't find Deal without an ID:
 activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:433:in `find_with_ids'
  activerecord (4.2.0) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:71:in `find'
  friendly_id (5.1.0) lib/friendly_id/finder_methods.rb:20:in `find'
  app/controllers/deals_controller.rb:70:in `show_opportunities'
```

This line where 70 with the error is "@deal = Deal.friendly.find(params[:id])" (see below)

```
controller/deals_controller.rb (using @Pavan feedback)
    # used so that old urls created for deals redirects to the new ones created
    # indeed with friendly_id, the url is taken from the title :/deals/title
    # but if we edit the deal title to deal/title2, the old url was still    working
    # we need to redirect the old url
    # source - github.com/norman/friendly_id/issues/385
    before_filter :find_deal,
       :only => [  :showcase ]
    before_filter :ensure_canonical_deal_path!,
      :only => [  :showcase ] 

def showcase    
    @deal = Deal.friendly.find(params[:id])   

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # showcase.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @deal }
    end
end 

def show_opportunities
    @deal = Deal.friendly.find(params[:deal])
    @opportunity = Opportunity.where('deal_id = ? AND deal_type = ?',
                             @deal.id, "high tech").first

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
end

protected

def find_deal
   @deal = Deal.friendly.find params[:id]
end
def ensure_canonical_deal_path!
   if request.path != deal_page_path(@deal)
        redirect_to deal_page_path(@deal, :format => params[:format]), :status => :moved_permanently
        return false
   end
end
```

app/views/deals/showcase.html.erb

```
<% if @deal.present? %>
   this is the beginning
   <%= render 'deals/deal_info_zone', locals:{deal: @deal} %>
   this is the end
<% end %>
```

views/deals/_deal_info_zone.html.erb

```
<div id="zoneA">      
  <div style="color:red;padding-top: 150px;">
    <%= link_to "view infos of Opportunities", deal_opportunities_modal_path, deal: @deal, remote: true %>
  </div>
</div>
```

views/deals/deal_opportunities_modal.js.erb

Here is the modal trigger via ajax: views/deals/opportunity_modal. 
Note here how I tried here to pass Deal but without success so that the line

```
$('body').append('<%= j render partial: "deals/deal_opportunities_modal", locals:{deal: @deal} %>'); 
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

/app/views/deals/_deal_opportunities_modal.html.erb

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-body"> 

          <%= @opportunity.name %> <br/>     

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
match '/deals/:id', # this is the Deal page
    to:   'deals#showcase',
    via:  'get',
    as:   :deal_page

match '/opportunity_modal',
    to:   'deals#show_opportunities',
    via:  'get',
    as:   :deal_opportunities_modal
```

How to make this work ?

**EDITED my question with Pavan feedback**

SOLUTION

I finally found my error:

What I did was wrong: indeed when I hovered above the link 'view opportunities' I could see the url that the linking was pointing at was localhost:3000/opportunity_modal. but how impossible! I can't give the same url to all the links 'view opportunities' that would appear in all the diffreent Deal pages(id=1, id=2,...).

So I changed the route to:

```
 match '/deals/:id/opportunity_modal',
 to: 'deals#show_opportunities',
 via: 'get',
 as: :deal_opportunities_modal
```

and it works!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NoMethodError - undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

`@deal` is **nil**, you need to define it in the `show_opportunities` method.

```
def show_opportunities
  @deal = Deal.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @opportunity = Opportunity.where('deal_id = ? AND deal_type = ?', @deal.id, "high tech").first
   respond_to do |format|
     format.js
   end
end
```

**Update:**

Firstly, change `deals = Deal.friendly.find(params[:id])` to `@deal = Deal.friendly.find(params[:id])` in `showcase` method.

And pass it as a `locals` in `<%= render 'deals/deal_info_zone' %>` like

`<%= render 'deals/deal_info_zone', locals:{deal: @deal} %>`, then pass it to `link_to` in `_deal_info_zone.html.erb`

```
<div id="zoneA">      
  <div style="color:red;padding-top: 150px;">
    <%= link_to "view infos of Opportunities", deal_opportunities_modal_path, deal: @deal, remote: true %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And finally access it in the `show_opportunities` method like `@deal = Deal.friendly.find(params[:deal])`

Comment: Isn't it bad like i.e not DRY ? I am repeating the same thing I have on the action above it (5 lines above it i am already defining @Deals on the action called #showcase), and they're both on the same view ( it's the same url I am loading that activate these 2 Deal controller's actions).

Comment: also isn't it bad to load twice : the same resource for performance/speed: when the page first loads it loads #showcase and the first time deal = Deal.friendly.find(params[:id]), then if I click on the link 'view opportunities', it will load again the same deal = Deal.friendly.find(params[:id]). Is it right?

Comment: couldn't i use/link or do sth not to repeat it?

Comment: @Mathieu You can pass it as `locals` to `<%= render 'deals/deal_info_zone' %>` but again you have to define it in the `show_opportunities` method to use here `@opportunity = Opportunity.where('deal_id = ? AND deal_type = ?', @deal.id, "high tech").first`

Comment: I tried it but it generated an Error= > see my question Edit

Comment: Actually if you look at my original code, I am trying already to pass the variable in the js render: $('body').append('<%= j render partial: "deals/deal_opportunities_modal", locals:{deal: @deal} %>'); 
$('#myModal').modal('show'). But does not work either.

Comment: I need to tell Rails: hey the @deal you need in #show_opportunities is just the deal you loaded when loading the page myapp.com/deal_id=5 so take this deal (the one with id=5)

Comment: sorry got it, will try

Comment: Not working, still getting the same error, would the full Error log be useful?

Comment: I edited my question: I added a piece of code in app/views/deals/showcase.html.erb :  <% if @deal.present? %>. I had not put the whole view code in the view here for the sake of simplicity maybe but maybe it's important.

Comment: Edited my question with your elements

Comment: @Mathieu Before the error message was showing in method `winalert` isn't it?

Comment: typo my bad: Error is in method `show_opportunities'. It's still not getting the deal.id! i've put wherever I could locals:{deal: @deal} : inside app/views/deals/showcase.html.erb, inside views/deals/deal_opportunities_modal.js.erb, but still no success

Comment: @Mathieu Try changing `<%= link_to "view infos of Opportunities", deal_opportunities_modal_path, deal: @deal, remote: true %>` to `<%= link_to "view infos of Opportunities", deal_opportunities_modal_path, deal: @deal.id, remote: true %>`

Comment: if not I'm wondering if this has not sth to do with friendely_ip, I'll check that after trying your suggestion

Comment: as regards friendly_id, I have not mentionned it because I have too many methods in my Deals controller but I have find_deal and ensure_canaonical_deal_path that you can see here on this page https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/issues/385, look for Parndt message in a code where he writes "ensure_canonical_product_path!"

Comment: I added in my controller the before_filter introduced for reasons related to friendly_id, maybe it's because of them my app can not find the ID.

Comment: hehe I think at last I found somebody with my weird problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32030893/couldnt-find-model-without-an-id-rails-4-custom-controller-action

Comment: other people blocked because .friendly.find did not work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732047/troubleshooting-friendly-id-w-rails-4-working-as-expected-in-rails-console-ge

Comment: But I am not sure it's due to Friendly _id: indeed if I put the opportunity = Opportunity.where('deal_id = ? AND ...inside the method #showcase, and do not use a modal but just try to display inside the normal page opportunity values such as  opportunity.name, it works. It's really when I move " opportunity = Opportunity.where('deal_id = ? AND ." inside another method called #show_opportunities and try to display it inside a modal that it goes crazy

Comment: Found it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! man, it was not related to friendly_id. What I did was wrong: indeed when I hovered above the link 'view opportunities' i could see the url that the linking was pointing at was localhost:3000/opportunity_modal. but how impossible! I can't give the same url to all the links 'view opportunities' that would appear in all the diffreent Deal pages(id=1, id=2,...). So I changed the route to:   match '/deals/:id/opportunity_modal',
    to:   'deals#show_opportunities',
    via:  'get',
    as:  :deal_opportunities_modal # path for rake route path, and it works!!!

Comment: I'll upvote your answer as it might not have worked without all the suggestions you made.